# SQL update by the same table with join another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I have a `Location` table in SQL Server:

```
   LocationId | LocationName |   Address
   ========================================
       15            AA         111 AAA
       17            CC         999 CCC
```

And I have a `Worksite` table with `WorksiteMark = Null`

```
  WorksiteId | WorksiteName |   Address   |  LocationId | WorksiteMark
   ======================================================================
       1            AA           111 AAA         15            Null
       2            P            23  P           15            Null
       3            F            78  F           15            Null
       4            H            16  H           17            Null
       5            CC           999 CCC         17            Null
       6            W            78  W           17            Null
```

Finally I need to update `WorksiteMark = WorksiteId` reference with `Location` table and I will delete the `Location` table

```
   WorksiteId | WorksiteName |   Address   | WorksiteMark
   ========================================================
       1            AA           111 AAA           1
       2            P            23  P             1
       3            F            78  F             1
       4            H            16  H             5
       5            CC           999 CCC           5
       6            W            78  W             5
```

Can you help me to create a script for updating `WorksiteMark = WorksiteId` referencing the `Location` table?

Thanks

Comment: Can You explain logic of worksitemark updated?

Comment: WorksiteName AA and CC reference 'Location table'

Comment: I need to update WorksiteMark because I need to delete Location table

Comment: But why 1 and 5 when there is no reference for the WorkSiteName or Location Id in Location table

Answer (score 0):

You need a double `JOIN` with your update, something like;

```
UPDATE W 
SET W.WorksiteMark = W2.WorksiteId
FROM Worksite AS W
INNER JOIN Location AS L 
       ON L.LocationId = W.LocationId
INNER JOIN Worksite AS W2
       ON W2.WorksiteName = L.LocationName
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This works for you.

```
Update W
SET W.WorksiteMark = L1.WorksiteId
FROM #Worksite AS W
INNER JOIN (Select L.LocationId,W2.WorksiteId FROM #Location L INNER JOIN 
            #Worksite W2 ON L.LocationName = W2.WorkSiteName) AS L1
     ON W.LocationId = l1.LocationId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Worksite]
SET WorksiteMark = (SELECT WorksiteId FROM [dbo].[Worksite] B WHERE B.WorksiteNAME = [dbo].[Location].LocationName)
from [dbo].[Worksite]
inner join [dbo].[Location] on [dbo].[Location].[LocationId] = [dbo].[Worksite].LocationId
```